# Split string for every X number of characters in a Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, excel-formula

I want to split a cell value into multiple lines by splitting a string by every 5th character.

**Example:** in below sample (screenshot) we have `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` in `A1` and in `B1` I want the string to be split after every 5th letter.

How can I do this?

[image: Screenshot of Google Sheet displaying desired outcome]

Comment: You might have meant `letter` instead of `word`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your `google-apps-script` tag, when Google Apps Script is used, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet and save the script. And, please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE(A1)` to a cell. By this, the result value is put to the cell.

```js
function SAMPLE(value) {
  const v = [...value];
  const res = [];
  while (v.length > 0) {
    res.push(v.splice(0, 5).join(""));
  }
  return res.join("\n");
}
```

Or, for example, if you want to use the custom function as `=SAMPLE(A1)` and `=SAMPLE(A1:D5)`, how about the following sample script?

```js
function output_(value) {
  const v = [...value];
  const res = [];
  while (v.length > 0) {
    res.push(v.splice(0, 5).join(""));
  }
  return res.join("\n");
}

function SAMPLE(values) {
  return Array.isArray(values) ? values.map(r => r.map(c => output_(c))) : output_(values);
}
```

#### Note:

- For example, when you use a built-in formula, how about the following formula? This formula supposes the text of `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` to a cell "A1". Please put this formula in the cell.

  ```
    =JOIN(CHAR(10),REGEXEXTRACT(A1,REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(.{0,5})","($1)")))
  ```

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: Hi @Tanaike first one is ok  but how to make it work for entire column as array formula. I tried ```=ArrayFormula(SAMPLE(A1))``` its not working.

Comment: @Demotry Thank you for replying. If you want to use multiple cells, please use my 2nd sample script. In this case, `ARRAYFORMULA` is not required to be used. It's like `=SAMPLE(A1:D5)`.

Comment: @Demotry By the way, about `I tried =ArrayFormula(SAMPLE(A1)) its not working.`, unfortunately, when I tested my 2 sample scripts using `=ArrayFormula(SAMPLE(A1))`, no error occurred. I could confirm that your expected result can be retrieved. So I cannot replicate your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide the detailed flow for replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it. For example, when you reopen the Spreadsheet and test it again, what result will you obtain?

Comment: Yes your first formula not works with Array. But your second formula worked for multiple cells.

Comment: @Demotry Thank you for replying. About `Yes your first formula not works with Array. But your second formula worked for multiple cells.`, yes, so I proposed 2 patterns. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike I really like your formula. Is there any way to modify it so that it only splits at spaces so words are kept whole? I will be doing this every 50 characters, but +/- 5 characters etc doesn't matter as long as words are still readable.

    =JOIN(CHAR(10),REGEXEXTRACT(A1,REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(.{0,5})","($1)")))

Comment: @David Dillard About your question, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: if I use that formula, it takes "night at the museum" and splits it into. 
<br>Night
<br> at t
<br>he Mu
<br>seum.
Is there any way to make it do this instead?
<br>Night
<br> at the
<br>Museum

Comment: @David Dillard Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Answer (score 1):

```
function test() {
  let s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  let a = s.split("").slice();
  let d = 0;
  s.split("").forEach((r, i) => {
    if (i > 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
      a.splice(i + d++, 0, '\n');
    }
  });
  Logger.log(a.filter(e => e).flat().join(""));
}

Execution log
8:20:25 PM  Notice  Execution started
8:20:24 PM  Info    ABCDE
FGHIJ
KLMNO
PQRST
UVWXY
Z
8:20:26 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```