# Method to split a string of numbers each time the next character is different from the previous

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, regexp-replace

I have a string of numbers like this:

`1113213211`

I want this to be split up in columns (I am using Google Sheets) so that the results would be this:

| Original | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1113213211 | 111 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 11 |

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71167715/split-string-for-every-x-number-of-characters-in-a-google-sheet) and it let me split it up some.  But I really don't know how it works so I struggled to modify it for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

This will put `|` between each change of character.  Then we split on that character:

```
=split(ArrayFormula(REDUCE("",MID(A1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(A1)),1),LAMBDA(a,b,IF(OR(a="",RIGHT(a)=b),a&b,a&"|"&b)))),"|")
```

If your strings contain `|` then choose a different character to delineate.

[image]

Comment: Awesome!  Works great!  It would be interesting to have you and @rockin each look at the others answer.  Give your thoughts on the differences!

Comment: @basstwo they both do similar things using different functions to put a throwaway character between each change then split on that throwaway character.  Neither approach has advantages above the other.  It come down to which you feel you like/understand better.

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
=let(a,flatten(regexextract(A2&"",regexreplace(A2&"","(.)","($1)"))),split(join("",map(a,{query(a,"offset 1");""},lambda(z,y,IF(z<>y,z&"",z)))),""))
```

[image]

Comment: Love the !!!  Works great!  It would be interesting to have you and @scott each look at the others answer.  Give your thoughts on the differences!

Comment: Well its just the use of different functions but eventually it boils down to finding the point where change happens and mark it and split it.